# loop through data using a label component C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to loop through some data I'm getting from a query using a label component.

This is my code to get the data and read it:

```
private void populatelblDesc() 
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query;
        query = "select de.emp_username, poc.order_no , poc.company_id_no from dc_emp de, purch_order_carton poc";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            lblDesc.Text = dr["emp_username"].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

That query returns:

```
**EMP_USERNAME**          **ORDER_NO**        **COMPANY_ID_NO**
Werner                    1                   1
Chris                     2                   1
Mike                      1                   2
Marc                      3                   1
```

Now I want to use my NEXT button to go through the data. And each individual column in query must display in separate labels. So on load the 1st label will display "Werner",2nd label "1", 3d label "1". Hitting next will display "Chris" in 1ste label, 2nd label "2"and 3d label "1" hitting next again will display "Mike" etc etc

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: On each `dr.Read()` condition you will get a next record..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your Values in a list somewhere:

```
List<String> LabelTextList = new List<String>();
private void populatelblDesc() 
{
    conn.Open();
    query = "select emp_username from dc_emp";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        this.LabelTextList.add(dr["emp_username"].ToString());
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

then use a integer value, starting with 0 and increase / decrease it by clicking next / prev

```
int i = 0;
public void next(){
    if (i+1 < this.LabelTextList.Count())
       lblText.text = this.LabelTextList[++i];
}
public void prev(){
    if (i-1 >= 0)
        lblText.text = this.LabelTextList[--i];
}
```

Add some validations if you are getting bellow 0 or greater than list size and you are done.

Comment: Thanks. This works! Just 2 questions. When I get to the last value and hit next again i'm getting an exception: "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: index" Thats obviously because there is no more data, but how do I fix that?

And then last question: I've got a different form where i need to do the same thing but with a larger query. Every time I run it I get "IndexOutOfRange"...

Comment: Thanks that's perfect. I'm going to edit my entire question a bit. I thought that was enough and it would help me but I'm running into other issues. If you have the time please read through my question again. Many thanks already!

Comment: just adapt the solution, and use 2 other counter like j and k. Then fill the other labels in the same way, start with j = 1 and K=2 ofc. Also the boundaries needs to be fixed then (if i-1 < count -2)

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work. I added another question. :) Please read.

Answer (score 3):

use a `BindingSource` in combination with `DataTable` and `DataBindings`.

Either drop one on your form and set `bs.DataSource` to the table or create one dynamically.

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Load(reader);
var bs = new BindingSource(table, null);
lblDesc.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "emp_username"),

btnNext.Click += ()
{
    bs.MoveNext();
};

btnPrev.Click += ()
{
    bs.MovePrevious();
};
```

You can even drop a BindingNavigator on your form and set `bindingNavigator1.BindingSource` to your BindingSource. It will manage the First/Previous/Next/Last logic without a single line of code.